# How to read a config file that has the fixed length definition to print the big file accordingly

Tags: unix, awk

I have config file customer.cfg that has 2 fields: Description and column length 
as below:

```
ID ; 10
First Name ; 20
Last Name ; 20
```

I also have a huge data file customer.dat that has the data that I want to read as you can see below:

```
1234567890John                Armless
9         Eric                Clapton                      
10        Roger               Waters
```

I would like to input LINE NUMBER, CONFIG_FILE_NAME and DATA_FILE_NAME and the awk should be able to print the data from the big file based on the format definition of the .cfg file:

For example:

Example 1

```
Input: 2,customer.cfg,customer.dat

Outputs:

DataFileName: customer.dat
Line: 2
ID:9
First Name:Eric
Last Name:Clapton
```

Example 2:

```
Input:all,customer.cfg,customer.dat

Outputs:

DataFileName: customer.dat
Line: 1
ID:1234567890
First Name:John
Last Name:Armless

DataFileName: customer.dat
Line: 2
ID:9
First Name:Eric
Last Name:Clapton

DataFileName: customer.dat
Line: 3
ID:10
First Name:Roger
Last Name:Waters
```

I have the same thing for other files such as products.cfg & products.dat,etc but always following the same standard as described above. So I want something generic enought to be used for other files too.

```
Considerations:
 - I want a solutions that uses AWK & printf
 - I can't install anything on this server.
 - My server is running AIX
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following script: (If you Gnu Awk version 4, you could simplify the script by using `FIELDWIDTHS` instead of calling `substr`)

```
#! /bin/bash
lineno=all
cfgfile="customer.cfg"
datfile="customer.dat"

awk -v line="$lineno" -f p.awk FS=";" "$cfgfile" "$datfile"
```

where `p.awk` is:

```
NR==FNR {
    a[++i]=$2
    next
}

line=="all" || FNR==line{
    print "DataFileName: " FILENAME
    print "Line "FNR
    id=getField(1,a[1])
    fn=getField(1+a[1],a[2])
    ln=getField(1+a[1]+a[2],a[3])
    print "ID:"id
    print "First Name: "fn
    print "Last Name: "ln
}

function getField(a,b,str) {
    str=substr($0,a,b)
    sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/,"",str)
    sub(/[[:blank:]]$/,"",str)
    return str
}
```

with output:

```
DataFileName: customer.dat
Line 1
ID:1234567890
First Name: John                
Last Name: Armless
DataFileName: customer.dat
Line 2
ID:9         
First Name: Eric                
Last Name: Clapton             
DataFileName: customer.dat
Line 3
ID:10        
First Name: Roger               
Last Name: Waters
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's more generic way of handling it without hardcoding the column names. This will allowing running the code on different files.

```
NF > 1 {
colwidth[FNR]=$2
colname[FNR]=$1
++colcount
}

NF < 2 {
        if(line=="all" || FNR==line) {
                printf("DataFileName: %s\n",FILENAME)
                printf("Line %d\n",FNR)
                nextcol=1
                for(eachcol=1; eachcol <= colcount; eachcol++ ) {
                        printf("%s : %s\n",colname[eachcol],substr($0,nextcol,colwidth[eachcol]))
                        nextcol+=colwidth[eachcol]
                }
        }
}
```

Here's what I get when I run the above code. I saved the code as /tmp/p.awk.

```
**awk -v line=2 -f /tmp/p.awk -F";" /tmp/customer.cfg /tmp/customer.dat**
DataFileName: /tmp/customer.dat
Line 2
ID  : 9
First Name  : Eric
Last Name  : Clapton

**awk -v line=all -f /tmp/p.awk -F";" /tmp/customer.cfg /tmp/customer.dat**
DataFileName: /tmp/customer.dat
Line 1
ID  : 1234567890
First Name  : John
Last Name  : Armless
DataFileName: /tmp/customer.dat
Line 2
ID  : 9
First Name  : Eric
Last Name  : Clapton
DataFileName: /tmp/customer.dat
Line 3
ID  : 10
First Name  : Roger
Last Name  : Waters
```

Comment: Hi, there is something wrong with your code. It didn't work here

Comment: Did you run it like `awk -v line=all -f p.awk -F";" customer.cfg customer.dat`?

Comment: yep, when it tries execute length(colname) it stops the execution and throws this error: `awk: Cannot read the value of  colname. It is an array name.` It's probably something related to the version of my awk.  Dunno

Comment: It seems your `awk` doesn't support `length(array)`. I modified it slightly and added colcount.

Answer (score 2):

@Håkon Hægland
I changed a little bit your code to make it generic enough so now I can use it for any *.dat *.cfg files I have here.

```
NR==FNR {
    a[++i]=$2
    b[i]=$1
    next
}

line=="all" || FNR==line{
    print "DataFileName: " FILENAME
    print "Line: "FNR
    linePos=1
    for (j=1;j<=i;j++){
      print b[j]":" getField(linePos,a[j])
      linePos+=a[j]
    }
    print "\n"
}

function getField(a,b,str) {
    str=substr($0,a,b)
    sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/,"",str)
    sub(/[[:blank:]]$/,"",str)
    return str
}
```

Thanks again.